# service worker android Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Tags: android, https, ssl-certificate, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I set up a **https** server on my machine and service sorker on that server.When i'm opening the site through desktop chrome browser after adding the certificate in the browser it opens fine.But when i try to open it in my android device it shows the following error.

**An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script.**

**https://www.aaa.com/swt1.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONS**E

**Error while installing service worker:  DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script.**

where **swt1.js** is my service worker file.

what is the issue .. is it installation of certificate or something related with service workers.

Comment: What is the URL which references the service worker?

Comment: the actual url that i'm hitting is    **https://www.aaa.com/-ddd-2345**. and in the index.html i registered a service worker **swt1.js**. when i open the link https://www.aaa.com/swt1.js it shows the service worker js file. but when i opens the actual page it throws the error

Comment: And if you open the network tab on Chrome, does it try to download swt1.js over HTTPS? Can you paste the request & response headers?

Comment: **Request** URL: `https://www.aaa.com/swt1.js`                                                                                                                        **Response  Header**                                                                                         Provisional headers are shown
Referer: `https://www.aaa.com/swt1.js`
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900P Build/LRX21T) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.23 Mobile Safari/537.36

Comment: This question is pretty specific to your server configuration. It would be much easier to debug with the real URL.

Comment: its my company's server. So it wont be accessible from outside.

Comment: I think the issue is related to adding certificate on android browser.

Comment: I know you are unable to use self-signed certificates so this might be the case, however it is difficult to debug like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in my self signed openssl certificate.For using a self signed certificate on android the certificate should have a "basic-constraint **CA=true**".In openssl by default the value is **CA=false**. so we need to change that value to true.
Below file is my **openssl.conf**.

```
HOME            = .
RANDFILE        = $ENV::HOME/.rnd

####################################################################
[ ca ]
default_ca  = CA_default        # The default ca section

[ CA_default ]

default_days    = 1000          # how long to certify for
default_crl_days= 30            # how long before next CRL
default_md  = sha256        # use public key default MD
preserve    = no            # keep passed DN ordering

x509_extensions = ca_extensions     # The extensions to add to the cert

email_in_dn = no            # Don't concat the email in the DN
copy_extensions = copy          # Required to copy SANs from CSR to cert

####################################################################
[ req ]
default_bits        = 4096
default_keyfile     = cakey.pem
distinguished_name  = ca_distinguished_name
x509_extensions     = ca_extensions
string_mask         = utf8only

####################################################################
[ ca_distinguished_name ]
countryName         = countryName
countryName_default     = countryName_default

stateOrProvinceName     = stateOrProvinceName
stateOrProvinceName_default = stateOrProvinceName_default

localityName            = localityName
localityName_default        = localityName_default

organizationName            = organizationName
organizationName_default    = Test CA, Limited

organizationalUnitName  = organizationalUnitName
organizationalUnitName_default  = Server Research Department

commonName          = commonName
commonName_default      = commonName

emailAddress            = emailAddress
emailAddress_default        = test@example.com

####################################################################
[ ca_extensions ]

subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always, issuer
basicConstraints = critical, CA:true
keyUsage = keyCertSign, cRLSign
```

If you cant find yours then make a file named **openssl.conf** with the above contents. and run this command

```
openssl req -x509 -config openssl.cnf -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -nodes -out server.pem -outform PEM
```

and for installing the certificate on android i used CAdroid app.